# If $E/F$ is a finite extension and $E$ is algebraically closed, then $F$ is perfect.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

The problem is

> Let $E$ be a finite extension of $F$ and suppose $E$ is algebraically closed. Show that $F$ is perfect.

I know that a field $F$ is called perfect if every irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ is separable, and a field $F$ is perfect if and only if it has characteristic $0$, or it has characteristic $p$ and $F=F^p$; then, fields of characteristic $0$ and finite fields are perfect.

Comment: If you’re willing to call in the big guns, if $E$ is algebraically closed, and $[E:F]<\infty$, then the characteristic is zero, and the degree is $2$. That’s Artin-Schreier. Since $F$ is of characteristic zero, it’s automatically perfect.

Comment: One can also exclude positive characteristic $p$ with the following easy lemma: If $F$ is a non-perfect field of characteristic $p$, then so is $F^{p^{-1}} \neq F$. Consequently, $F \subsetneq F^{p^{-1}} \subsetneq F^{p^{-2}} \subsetneq ...$ is an infinite tower of fields within $E$, contradicting $E|F$ being finite.

Comment: Related:  [If L∣K is a finite extension of fields then K is perfect iff L is perfect](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099199/if-l-mid-k-is-a-finite-extension-of-fields-then-k-is-perfect-iff-l-is-perfect)

Answer (score -1):

You can prove:

- If every extension of *F* splits, then *F* is perfect.
- Let *F* ⊆ *K* ⊆ *E* a tower of fields. If *E/F* is algebraic and splits, then *K/F* splits.

And finally use the definition of algebraically closed.

Comment: I do not understand this answer. What does it mean here for an extension of $F$ to split?